# Strict five minute comment editing window not in line with reality - improvement suggestion

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

There is an **arbitrary** limit of five minutes on editing comments.

If there has been no other activity on that particular Q&A then the abitrary limit can be a hindrance to the formulation of a good comment.

For example, someone might write a comment quickly (other people will see that comment) and need some time to add pertinent authoritative references. That time will typically, in my experience, be between 301 and 480 seconds.

**I propose** that the arbitrary time limit be removed if there has been no other additional activity on the Q&A post.

Comment: "*For example, someone might write a comment quickly (other people will see that comment) and need some time to add pertinent authoritative references.*" Why couldn't you wait those "301 and 480 seconds" to get the authoritative references *first*? Indeed, there have been plenty of times when I went to get references before making a comment, only to find references that proved what I was about to say was *wrong*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Because then other people may be using their time unnecessarily to come up with the same comment.

Comment: @gnat No, that and the current answer to this question just reinforce my request. I might revisit this question at some time to reword it.

Answer (score 20):

If there was no other activity on the post, then there is an existing solution - just delete your comment and repost the edited version. There is no need for a more complicated solution.

Comment: But then OP will get two notifications and may get annoyed...

Comment: @user000001 I was under the impression that editing a comment also renews the notification, doesn't it? (If you check a comment within those first 5 minutes, then the user edits their comment, I thought that the notification pops back up, but I might be wrong.)

Comment: That does mean re-creating any links already used and re-doing the formatting. There's no point arbitrarily making it more effort than needed. Anyway, I'll see what other lead balloons I can come up with :)

Comment: @DavyM No, edits to a comment don't renew the notification.  But if you change who you @ in the post, it'll update who is notified.  So if you @ someone you didn't before, they'll get a notification after the edit.

Comment: @AndrewMorton If re-creating the rest of the comment is too difficult, then just post a new comment with the link you want to add.

Comment: @Servy Ah, that must be it then, when I faced this, someone had commented on a post of my own, I checked the notification, then about a minute later it popped up again, and the edit to the comment was adding "@Davym" to the start of their comment, so it must have fallen under that case you mentioned, since I was notified as the post owner at first, but when they edited it, it added the @ mention and notified me for a second time.